# RecyclerView scrolling very slow and laggy

Tags: android, performance, scroll, android-recyclerview

Hey I am using recyclerview with list-card design and on every card I have an image, not a large one it weights 1.5 mb I am loading 12 cards but the scrolling is so laggy I tried using PICASSO and it didn't helped, the thing is when I replace the image with a much smaller one (300 bytes) it scrolles well but it doesn't solve my problem..

the relevant part of the cards xml is:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/card_item"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:clickable="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">



        <RelativeLayout

            android:id="@+id/cont_card_content"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF">



            <ImageView

                android:id="@+id/im_item_icon"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="170dp"

                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

as I was saying I tried using PICASSO and it didn't helped

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.bg_partyt).into(holder.imageView);
```

any ideas?

Comment: 1.5mb is large so try using Picasso's .fit() method. fit() will measure the dimensions of the target ImageView (@+id/im_item_icon) and then uses Picasso's own resize() method to reduce the image size to the dimensions of the target ImageView. 

More info here: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Comment: Can you post the layout code which includes recyclerView?

Comment: I am trying to use the .fit() but it just doesn't show the image at all.

Answer (score 1):

your image is way to big.

You could try using Glide instead of picasso.  It handles big images a little bit better https://github.com/bumptech/glide